# Gradle task for deploying vendored libraries into local maven repository

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, deployment, gradle

I'm trying to figure out how to get gradle to deploy some jar files into the local maven repository, to support the rest of the build system. A dependency that I have against something has its own dependency on `jndi:jndi:1.2.1` which isn't available in jcenter or maven central.

What I've done (as suggested in the docs of my dependency - Jira for what it's worth) is downloaded the `jndi.jar` file, and have run the following:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=lib/jndi.jar -DgroupId=jndi \
-DartifactId=jndi -Dversion=1.2.1 -Dpackaging=jar
```

That works fine. But I'd like gradle to be able to execute a task that will install this file to the local maven repository, to make CI easier and to make on-boarding other developers easier.

I've tried to follow the [recommendations here](http://www.alonsoruibal.com/my-gradle-tips-and-tricks/) (with [code](https://github.com/albertoruibal/jmini3d/blob/master/gwtgl/build.gradle)), but I'm not having much luck. Here's an excerpt from my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

artifacts {
    archives(file('lib/jndi.jar')) {
        name 'jndi'
        group 'jndi'
        version '1.2.1'
    }
    archives(file('lib/jta-1_0_1B.jar')) {
        name 'jta'
        group 'jta'
        version '1.0.1'
    }
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: 'file://' + new File(System.getProperty('user.home'), '.m2/repository').absolutePath)
        }
    }
}
install.dependsOn(uploadArchives)
```

And when I run the install task:

```
$ gradle --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.4
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2015-05-05 08:09:24 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     5c9c3bc20ca1c281ac7972643f1e2d190f2c943c

Groovy:       2.3.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.4 compiled on April 29 2014
JVM:          1.8.0_11 (Oracle Corporation 25.11-b03)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.10.3 x86_64

$ gradle install
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar UP-TO-DATE
:uploadArchives FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':uploadArchives'.
> Could not publish configuration 'archives'
   > A POM cannot have multiple artifacts with the same type and classifier. Already have MavenArtifact engage-jira:jar:jar:null, trying to add MavenArtifact engage-jira:jar:jar:null.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Now, I don't really want to install my artifacts to the local maven repository - just the transitive dependencies. I don't mind if my artifact is installed though.

**Update - Solution:**

So, this seems to do the trick:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()

    maven { 
        url './lib' 
    }
}

dependencies {
    runtime files(
       'lib/jndi/jndi/1.2.1/jndi-1.2.1.jar', 
       'lib/jta/jta/1.0.1/jta-1_0_1.jar'
    )
    runtime fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar')
}
```

I moved the libs into the folder structure expected by maven, added the local folder structure into the repositories stanza, and added the runtime files into dependencies.

No stuffing about with the localhost global repository, executing command lines, or anything like that. It'd nice to have better support for local transitive dependencies, but how often is that required in practise?

Comment: So you want to overwrite the final-version of jndi and jta for each time you build your app?  The plugin simply says that "this version already exists, and it is a final version of the library". If you want to re-install it, you could try to delete it from your local repo first.

Comment: It's not about reinstalling. When a new developer wants to work on this project I don't want them to have to run a series of `mvn install ...` just to get started. Since I have a build system (gradle) I figured I should be able to use that to execute the commands. I'm not tied to using the maven plugin either.

Comment: Also, I'm guessing the error that I'm seeing is due to the plugin trying to "install" my project artifact using the values present in the last archives block. I don't think the two archives are trying to be installed at all.

Comment: Maybe you could have a "preInstall" task that installs the artifacts in the new developers local repo?

Comment: @nilsmagnus yes, that's what I'm trying to figure out how to write. Any tips?

Comment: task preInstall(){}  preInstall.dependsOn(uploadArchives) ?

Comment: @nilsmagnus but what would go inside preInstall? The "artifacts" block in my original code is wrong and doesn't do what I'd expect.

Answer (score 4):

Gradle allows [adding dependencies directly to your build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:file_dependencies), without first installing them to the local repository.

```
dependencies {
    runtime files('lib/jndi.jar', 'lib/jta-1_0_1B.jar')
    runtime fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar')
}
```

That should work right away. Eventually, you might want to set up a Maven repository manager, e.g. [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/), install your missing libraries there, and refer to them in your build like this:

```
repositories {
    maven { url "http://192.168.x.x/artifactory/local-repository" }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "jndi:jndi:1.2.1"
    compile "jta:jta:1.0.1"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that got me onto the right track. I moved the jar files into a structure required by maven, then created a gradle repository pointing at the local directory. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Also, this is the only java project I work on - and it's a "simple" integration component. If I was doing real dev in java I would setup my own repository as suggested.